# Filtering data based on word in string in R dataf

Tags: r, filter, multiple-columns, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a dataframe that need to be cleaned up to include a treatment variable (column). The information is currently stored in the `plant` variable but I need it to be its own column. I’ve tried filter in my pipe but no luck yet. The two treatments should be `Control` and `Covered`
[Access Data Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zb9vajtg63ctuex/AAAz0YhfzdvVQMVU_FL7ubgTa?dl=0)

```
library (tidyverse)
setwd("/Users/israel/Desktop/Ecology Paper")
raw.data<- read.csv ("Complete Dataset_01_17_20.csv", header = TRUE)

flowers<- raw.data %>% select (1,3:35, 100:115) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(replace_na(., 0))) %>%
  group_by(location.ID, Year) %>% 
  gather (key= plant, value=count, -location.ID, -Year) %>% 
  group_by(location.ID, Year, as.factor(plant))  %>% filter (contains(Control))
```

Comment: Can you include some illustrative reproducible data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are trying to filter based on the 'plant', use `str_detect` (or `grepl` from `base R`) on the 'plant' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
raw.data %>% 
   select (1,3:35, 100:115) %>% 
   mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na, 0)  %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(location.ID, Year), names_to ='plant',
            values_to = 'count') %>%       
  filter(str_detect(plant, 'Control')) %>%
  group_by(location.ID, Year)
```

The `group_by` step is not clear.  If we want to `filter` `any` 'Control' then have the `group_by` before the `filter` and wrap with `any` i.e. `any(str_detect(plant, 'Control'))`